# Graduate application: Institutions that I have attended

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, application

I am applying for a Master's degree program, and in the application I'm asked to list the institutions that I have attended and to attach the transcript for each. I have attended school A for a Bachelor degree in a related discipline to the program I am applying for. But later, I attended another undergraduate School B which is completely irrelevant to my major. It would take me a while to get a transcript from school B.

My question is: Must I mention School B in my graduate application? Or should I just mention A since it is the one relevant to my major and the program I'm applying for ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safest stance: mention both.

School B may be "*irrelevant to my major*", but mentioning it is going to add to the application. Though we are talking about an application here, and not about a CV, something related happens in a typical CV too. You assign more significance to stuff that is more relevant to your major, you put a general heading *Other relevant information*, and include other *not-so-relevant* bits over there. Over here, you need not put a separate heading. but still, mentioning it (with a clear pronouncement that you've done it though it ain't directly relevant to your major), can only add to the application. What do you lose by mentioning it!

As far as the issue of transcript from B is concerned, apply for the same - that would serve the purpose of authentication. If there isn't enough time to get it before the application deadline, write an email to the department saying that you have applied for the same on ( *insert date here* ), and some delay in receiving it is anticipated. If possible, you can forward the application (for the transcript) too, along with this email, to serve as a direct confirmation. Maybe, you can also add that you will communicate the same as soon as it is received. That would be a correct and safe statement. And I don't think your masters-degree-school will consider it a wrong stance, since the crux of their decision will certainly not be based on this part. This is only going to be a point in your favor (if it does count at all), but certainly isn't the bone of contention for your application.

Comment: Also, if you have an official copy of your transcript from the other school, I'd send it along (and if you don't, get a copy and scan it in, just for future use).

Comment: In some countries, (germany for sure) admissions offices need to know the number of terms you studied with any university to calcuate certain financial grants which may or may not apply. Failure to disclose those may result in an application to be rejected or even an offered spot to be canceled. Talking from experience!